# std::find for vector containing pointers

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl, polymorphism

I have a class Node and a derived class ChildNode as given below

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class Node
{
public:
    int nodeId;
    bool operator==(int id) const { return (this->nodeId ==id);}; //used in STL Find function
    Node(int id)
    {
        this->nodeId=id;
    }
    ~Node(void)
    {
    }
    virtual void SaySomeThing()
    {
        cout<<"Hey! I am node"<<endl;
    }
};
class ChildNode:public Node
{
public:
    ChildNode(int id):Node(id){};
    virtual void SaySomeThing()
    {
        cout<<"Hey! I am a child node"<<endl;
    }
};
```

Now in main I call `NodeVectorTest` method having vector object which contains nodes

```
void NodeVectorTest()
{
    vector<Node> nodes;
    Node *node=new Node(22);
    nodes.push_back(*node);
    delete node;
    node=new ChildNode(23);
    nodes.push_back(*node);
    delete node;
    node=new Node(33);
    nodes.push_back(*node);
    delete node;

    //Find node
    vector<Node>::iterator nodePosition;
    int nodeId=23;
    nodePosition =find(nodes.begin(),nodes.end(),nodeId);
    if(nodePosition == nodes.end()) { ///we didnt find the node id ..

        cerr<<"node id "<< nodeId <<" Could not be found "<<endl;

        return ;
    }

    else{ //now we have the right node to do our desired stuff
        (*nodePosition).SaySomeThing();
    }
}
```

when I found node 23 it is converted into Node object instead of Node*, so that it is showing output as `Hey! I am node` to achieve polymorphism, I converted this `vector<Node> nodes;` to `vector<Node*> nodes;` as code given below

```
vector<Node*> nodes;
Node *node=new Node(22);
nodes.push_back(node);
node=new ChildNode(23);
nodes.push_back(node);
node=new Node(33);
nodes.push_back(node);

//Find node
vector<Node*>::iterator nodePosition;
int nodeId=23;
nodePosition =find(nodes.begin(),nodes.end(),nodeId);

if(nodePosition == nodes.end()) { ///we didnt find the node id ..

    cerr<<"node id "<< nodeId <<" Could not be found "<<endl;

    return ;
}

else{ //now we have the right node to do our desired stuff
    (*nodePosition).SaySomeThing();
}
```

When I change it into this I got the following error

> Error 1   error C2446: '==' : no conversion from 'const int' to 'Node *'  microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xutility
>   Error   2   error C2040: '==' : 'Node *' differs in levels of indirection from 'const int'  microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xutility

Any help in this regard ?

Comment: Non-leaf classes should be abstract; that simple guideline would have saved you a ton of headache.

Comment: You'll probably want to mark your constructor `explicit` as currently you can directly assign an int to a `Node` instance which doesn't seem like a good idea.

Comment: @ArneMertz, there is nothing like that. I am pushing it first, it will make another object of node, then I am deleting so there is no undefined behavior. If there is something like that kindly enlighten me. Regards

Comment: @Zaksh sorry, I misread the examples a bit - then it's another issue: in `NodeVectorTest` you needlessly create the `Node`s on the free store instead of on the stack. The whole `new`-`delete` orgy is of no use and needlessly slowing your program down.

Comment: @zaksh consider `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Node>>`

Comment: @ArneMertz thanks for your concern, that was just to make my case clear. I am using the second thing in my code.

Comment: @Yakk I am new to STL, let me read that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The elements of `nodes` is the *pointer* to `Node`, not `Node`. So, you should use `std::find_if`.

```
nodePosition = find_if(nodes.begin(), nodes.end(),
    [nodeId](Node *p) { return *p == nodeId; });
```

PS. Although `c++11` is the tag of your question, you didn't use any nice features of C++11!

PS2. Notice your first example with `vector<Node>` will occur *slicing problem*.

PS3. And in your first example, you need not and should not use `new`. just `nodes.push_back(Node(22));` or `nodes.emplace_back(22);`.

Comment: Shouldn't this be `find_if`?

Comment: Thanks @ikh, that is what I needed. I tried find_if, but was unable to figure out how can I use it my scenario.

Answer (score 2):

Please note that by default `find` will use an `operator==` that compares an object to another object of the same type. In this case you need to overload bool `operator==(const Node*, const Node*)` which is not possible. A far better option for you is to use find with predicate, which is implemented in the function [std::find_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find).

Comment: You cannot overload operators if none of the operands is a UDT. Pointers are *not* considered as UDTs, so overloading `operator=(Node const*, Node const*)` is not only unwise, it is impossible.

Comment: @ArneMertz fair enough. I have fixed my wording. Thank you